# Jackson fails with "Cannot construct instance of WorkpoolId (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory"

Tags: jackson

I have the following class

```
public class WorkpoolId implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    private Long id = null;

    @JsonCreator
    public WorkpoolId(@JsonProperty("workpoolId") long id) {
        this.id = Long.valueOf(id);
    }

    public WorkpoolId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public WorkpoolId(String id) {
        this.id = Long.valueOf(id);
    }

    private WorkpoolId() {
    }
}
```

when mapping

> "workpoolId":1

to this class I get a

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `WorkpoolId` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)

Why is jackson not able to use the long constructor for the number value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because your `WorkpoolId` does not have access to field `workpoolId` it is not in its context anuymore. When your JSON is deserialized it could be deserialized either as an

- independent object (having no field `workpoolId`, it **IS** the `workbookId`)
- field object value in an object containing -say `Data` - it **that** might be named as *workpoolId*.

Now the use of workbookId could be usable for the JsonCreator in `Data` when constructing its field *workpoolId*.

To clarify this a bit, here is an example of possible `Data` class:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Data {
    private WorkpoolId workpoolId;
    @JsonCreator // here it is a property!
    public Data(@JsonProperty("workpoolId") long id) {
        this.workpoolId = new WorkpoolId(id);
    } 
}
```

Json would be like `{"workpoolId":1}`

To have it work just remove the annotation `@JsonProperty("workpoolId")` from the attribute declaration. Actually the whole `@JsonCreator` annotation is not needed.